# Tridiagonal matrix

Tags: matrices

How can I reduce the size of the symbols in every element in the tridiagmatrix? It gets to large, and the ddots don't point in a straight diagonal line, the don't connect with each other. That's because I have about 5 letters in every diagelement! How can I fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: A brute-force method -- I'm afraid I can't provide something more elegant since no information as to the size or structure of the off-diagonal elements is available -- would be to prepend either `\scriptstyle` (for a linear reduction of 30%) or even `\scriptscriptstyle` (for a linear reduction of 50%) before each and every cell of the matrix whose font size you decide need to be reduce. As I said, this is pure brute force, not elegant at all.